# Failed to parse input string "31-Dec-2019" ERROR

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

Data Type of my date column in the big query table is String.

Format of the date:  31-Dec-2019

I have records for 2018, 2019, 2020 years.

Now I want to filter out the data after 2020-01-01.

With the below code, where-condition is not working here and returning all the records of the table.

```
Select
*
from table T
where date > '2020-01-01'
```

Tried the below and their respective errors: 
PARSE_DATE('%d-%m-%Y',SUBSTR(date,1,12)) - **Failed to parse input string "31-Dec-2019"**

CAST( date as DATE) > '2020-01-01' -- **returning all the records in the table/where condition is not working**

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **%b** for abreviated month name.

```
select PARSE_DATE('%d-%b-%Y',SUBSTR('31-Dec-2019',1,12))
```